# Spring 3.2 HTTP Request parameter _csrf is becoming null before CSRF Filter

Tags: java, spring, jsp, http, csrf

I am using Spring 3.2.6 and Spring Security 3.2.4, I have enabled CSRF filter for POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods. CSRF filter works fine mostly however it intermittently fails due to null CSRF token even though it exists in the JSP as a hidden parameter as follows. And this strange issue occurs from time to time then disappears and does not happen at all for a while then starts happening intermittently again.

This is the parameter in the JSP;

It seems somehow the HTTP request parameter is being nulled before CSRF filter is invoked.

Filters are invoked in the following order SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, ConcurrentSessionFilter, CsrfFilter and so on ...

Tomcat version is 7.0.23

Below is the error I get;

org.springframework.security.web.csrf.InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a long shot, but this behavior can be triggered by keeping references to the HttpServletRequest (for example storing the HttpServletRequest instance in the session) which prevents Tomcat from recycling the ServletRequest object.

Without recycling of the instance, the "is parsed" flag (which indicates that the query parameters are parsed) is never reset, resulting in Tomcat not processing the URL on the next request leaving you without any query parameters.

Comment: Thank you Dittmer, the CSRF token is in a hidden field in the JSP not a query parameter. Is this flag applies to the request parameters as input fields?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, you have to consult the tomcat source in order to be sure. However, this is just one example that might lead to this kind of behaviour.